# Как прокрутить один из двух скроллбаров наверх?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется два независимых скроллбара  на странице. 
`scrollTo(0, 0)`  перестал работать после добавление второго скроллбара. 
**Как прокрутить один из скроллбаров наверх?** (допустим, при onclick)

---

UPD: при нажатии на кнопку, хочется, чтобы желто-зеленый блок поднялся наверх. Что я делаю не так?

```js
function scrollToTOp() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

```css
html, body, aside, main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside, main {
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}



main {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<aside>
<button style="width:100%" onclick="scrollToTOp()">Нажми</button>В середине разговора про политические действия Анна Павловна разгорячилась.
— Ах, не говорите мне про Австрию! Я ничего не понимаю, может быть, но Австрия никогда не хотела и не хочет войны. Она предает нас. Россия одна должна быть спасительницей Европы. Наш благодетель знает свое высокое призвание и будет верен ему. Вот одно, во что я верю. Нашему доброму и чудному государю предстоит величайшая роль в мире, </aside>


<main>— Eh bien, mon prince. Gênes et Lucques ne sont plus que des apanages, des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous préviens que si vous ne me dites pas que nous avons la guerre, si vous vous permettez encore de pallier toutes les infamies, toutes les atrocités de cet Antichrist (ma parole, j'y crois) — je ne vous connais plus, vous n'êtes plus mon ami, vous n'êtes plus мой верный раб, comme vous dites 1. Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте. Je vois que je vous fais peur 2, садитесь и рассказывайте.
Так говорила в июле 1805 года известная Анна Павловна Шерер, фрейлина и приближенная императрицы Марии Феодоровны, встречая важного и чиновного князя Василия, первого приехавшего на ее вечер. Анна Павловна кашляла несколько дней, у нее был грипп, как она говорила (грипп был тогда новое слово, употреблявшееся только редкими). В записочках, разосланных утром с красным лакеем, было написано без различия во всех:
«Si vous n'avez rien de mieux à faire, Monsieur le comte (или mon prince), et si la perspective de passer la soirée chez une pauvre malade ne vous effraye pas trop, je serai charmée de vous voir chez moi entre 7 et 10 heures. Annette Scherer» 3.
— Dieu, quelle virulente sortie! 4 — отвечал, нисколько не смутясь такою встречей, вошедший князь, в придворном, шитом мундире, в чулках, башмаках и звездах, с светлым выражением плоского лица.
Он говорил на том изысканном французском языке, на котором не только говорили, но и думали наши деды, и с теми, тихими, покровительственными интонациями, которые свойственны состаревшемуся в свете и при дворе значительному человеку. Он подошел к Анне Павловне, поцеловал ее руку, подставив ей свою надушенную и сияющую лысину, и покойно уселся на диване.
.</main>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить [mcve]

Comment: Не особо минимальный, но возможно самодостаточный и воспроизводимый частично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам хочется, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку желто-зеленый блок поднялся наверх. Но почему то вы пытаетесь поднять на верх не его, а window.
Поднять определенный блок можно так:

```js
const YellowGreenBlock = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]
function scrollToTOp() {
   YellowGreenBlock.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
html, body, aside, main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

aside, main {
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red);
}



main {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<button style="width:100%" onclick="scrollToTOp()">Нажми</button>
<aside>
В середине разговора про политические действия Анна Павловна разгорячилась.
— Ах, не говорите мне про Австрию! Я ничего не понимаю, может быть, но Австрия никогда не хотела и не хочет войны. Она предает нас. Россия одна должна быть спасительницей Европы. Наш благодетель знает свое высокое призвание и будет верен ему. Вот одно, во что я верю. Нашему доброму и чудному государю предстоит величайшая роль в мире, 
</aside>


<main>— Eh bien, mon prince. Gênes et Lucques ne sont plus que des apanages, des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte. Non, je vous préviens que si vous ne me dites pas que nous avons la guerre, si vous vous permettez encore de pallier toutes les infamies, toutes les atrocités de cet Antichrist (ma parole, j'y crois) — je ne vous connais plus, vous n'êtes plus mon ami, vous n'êtes plus мой верный раб, comme vous dites 1. Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте. Je vois que je vous fais peur 2, садитесь и рассказывайте.
Так говорила в июле 1805 года известная Анна Павловна Шерер, фрейлина и приближенная императрицы Марии Феодоровны, встречая важного и чиновного князя Василия, первого приехавшего на ее вечер. Анна Павловна кашляла несколько дней, у нее был грипп, как она говорила (грипп был тогда новое слово, употреблявшееся только редкими). В записочках, разосланных утром с красным лакеем, было написано без различия во всех:
«Si vous n'avez rien de mieux à faire, Monsieur le comte (или mon prince), et si la perspective de passer la soirée chez une pauvre malade ne vous effraye pas trop, je serai charmée de vous voir chez moi entre 7 et 10 heures. Annette Scherer» 3.
— Dieu, quelle virulente sortie! 4 — отвечал, нисколько не смутясь такою встречей, вошедший князь, в придворном, шитом мундире, в чулках, башмаках и звездах, с светлым выражением плоского лица.
Он говорил на том изысканном французском языке, на котором не только говорили, но и думали наши деды, и с теми, тихими, покровительственными интонациями, которые свойственны состаревшемуся в свете и при дворе значительному человеку. Он подошел к Анне Павловне, поцеловал ее руку, подставив ей свою надушенную и сияющую лысину, и покойно уселся на диване.
.</main>
```